# How to keep only speicific row from dataframe Python 2.7 pandas

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I would like to keep only row which contains only 3 dots :

The dataframe :

```
        col1             
0       FG-1.52.23          
1       FG-1.9.23.52          
2       FG-5.58.23          
3       FG-8.84.2         
4       FG-4.52.3.7         
5       FG-3.2         
6       FG-1
```

The result :

```
        col1                     
0       FG-1.9.23.52          
1       FG-4.52.3.7
```

Comment: aren't these 4 points?

Comment: @sophods 3 dots though.

Comment: yes sorry my mistake 3 dots

Comment: try using https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html to split the strings by `.`, then get the length of each and keep only those with length equal to what you want (4 if you want 3 dots).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) here.

```
df[df['col1'].str.count('\.').eq(3)]

           col1
1  FG-1.9.23.52
4   FG-4.52.3.7
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply !

Comment: If the answer solves your issue consider upvoting and accepting this as the answer. Cheers ;) @JulieHardy